# Passport strategy for user authentication in hyperledger composer angular2 app

Tags: passport.js

I am a first-timer in implementing user authentication on a web application. Below are some details for the app:

- Its a hyperledger composer angular2 application generated using `yo
  hyperledger-composer` command
- Existing set of username and password available

User identities are successfully issued in composer.

Should I use passport-saml strategy as suggested in https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml? Or is there a better option considering Yo generates angular2 app (many angular 1.x examples available for other strategies like passport-local and passport-http)?

What are the details I will need from the existing database if passport-saml is the best option?

I checked [Using passport-http on Hyperledger composer REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734046/using-passport-http-on-hyperledger-composer-rest-api), but it doesn't seem to answer (here the user wants to use userID and userSecret).

Answer (score 0):

See here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer//integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html

You can use the COMPOSER_PROVIDERS environment variable  - to specify - the Passport strategies that the REST server should use to authenticate clients of the REST API. You choose, the strategy best suited to you - I can't advise if passport-saml is suitable for you, that's your decision :-) . The parameters (example shown for providers.json) are quite similar to the example shown in the docs. Some of the information from the Github repo you posted already has some sample information in the config parameters section.

Comment: I have checked the link earlier. It has a sample for GitHub authentication. I don't want to use any of the third party strategy.. so saml seems to be the available choice. I am implementing any type of user authentication for the first time, so I was wondering if there are guidelines for selecting saml. This question is probably better suited for @passport team.